# What is this Slot for in My Flights Overhead Panel?

Tags: cabin-design

Does anybody know what this slot is for in my planes overhead panel? I think it was an airbus A320 or similar if that helps. Opening it revealed what looked like a a black socket, but not for electrical plugs.

[image]

Thanks in advance,

James

Comment: No picture of the black socket? That would be helpful. Can you describe it in more detail

Comment: Did the black socket look like this or similar?  See this [LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HodV.jpg)

Comment: Yes it did, that kind of circle but all black and possibly plastic. It had the smaller hole in the middle too.

Comment: If the black socket looks like one in the picture sent in my link above it could be an auxiliary  oxygen connection for a flight attendant's use. I have not seen one like this in a similar location so it would be interesting if someone can provide a concrete answer.